# set variable if...then javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, toggle

I'm trying to set a variable and upload it to my database depending on what text displays on the page. I am using a simple if...then in javascript, it says that the variable is undefined. Is there another way to set the variable?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
oldTextAry = new Array();
function changeText (fieldObj, newTexStr) {
    if (newTexStr == fieldObj.innerHTML) {
        fieldObj.innerHTML = oldTextAry[fieldObj.id];
        var waswere = 1;
    } else {
        oldTextAry[fieldObj.id] = fieldObj.innerHTML;
        fieldObj.innerHTML = newTexStr;
        var waswere = 2;
    }
}
function displayWasWere () {
        document.write(waswere);
}
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<HTML>
    <a href="#" onclick="changeText(this,'were');" id="text1link">was</a><br/>
    <a href="#" onClick="displayWasWere();" id="waswere" name="waswere">show variable</a>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make `waswere` as global var:

```
var waswere;
oldTextAry = new Array();
function changeText (fieldObj, newTexStr) {
    if (newTexStr == fieldObj.innerHTML) {
        fieldObj.innerHTML = oldTextAry[fieldObj.id];
        waswere = 1;
    } else {
        oldTextAry[fieldObj.id] = fieldObj.innerHTML;
        fieldObj.innerHTML = newTexStr;
        waswere = 2;
    }
}
function displayWasWere () {
    document.write(waswere);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is defined in the scope of the first function.  Make the variable global and you should be ready to roll.